# NoClassDefFoundError when the jar exists, specifically for mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar

Tags: java, javac, mysql-connector

I want to make sure I can connect to the MySQL server I have running locally with a simple Java class.

To test the connection I want to use the `MysqlDataSource` class that comes with the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar`

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and have the jar located at:`/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar`.

Then I run the compiler command: `$ javac -cp "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar" App.java`

Then: `$ java App`

And get the following output error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/jdbc/MysqlDataSource
        at App.main(App.java:15)...
```

Output of `$ mysql --version`:
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

This is all my `App.java` file contains:

````
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("test");
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");

        Connection conn;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }    
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `java App`, you must specify a classpath to include the jar at runtime. Like,

```
java -cp "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:." App
```

Comment: Do I do that alongside the ```javac -cp "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar" App.java``` command I was using?

Comment: You don't need the connector at compile time. Just run time. And it depends on the version of Java and what you're trying to do. In recent versions, you can execute `App.java` with `java` without compiling. But I would recommend you stick with `javac App.java` and then the command I gave here.